# Absolutely positioned overlay passes hover event in spite of `pointer-event:none` in CSS

Tags: html, css

In below example although `.overlay` fully covers `.positioner` and `.overlay` has `pointer-events: none`, `.positioner` still react to hover. I expected what `.overlay` will not pass cursor events.

```css
.positioner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #FAD7A0;
}

.positioner:hover {
  background: #85C1E9;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioner">
  <div class="overlay"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, when you hover `.overlay`, you also hover its parent, which is `.positioner`, since they are positioned on top of each other.
If you move `.overlay` below `.positioner`, it will not trigger hover effect on its parent:

```css
.positioner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #FAD7A0;
}

.positioner:hover {
  background: #85C1E9;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioner">
  <div class="overlay"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` only applies to `.overlay`, not its parent. You would need to move it to `.positioner`, in order to make it work on it as well. You can check the the docs at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

You put the overlay inside the positioner (as a child element).

It's not clear to me if you want to cover the entire positioner element using the overlay or just its contents. In the latter case, you should not put a `hover` pseudo-class on the positioner itself, I guess.

So I assume that you want to hide the positioner itself using the overlay, so that its `hover` will not be triggered. In that case, I would expect the overlay to be placed in front of the positioner. For that, the overlay should at least be a sibling of the positioner within the DOM.

When testing around, I found out that using `pointer-events` did not work as I expected. But assuming that the overlay should be able to work just fine without it, I simply removed it.

This is my end result:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (input.checked) {
    overlay.style.display = null;
  }
  else {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
.container, .positioner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.positioner {
  background: #FAD7A0;
}

.positioner:hover {
  background: #85C1E9;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked><label>Overlay active</label>

<div class="container">
  <div class="positioner"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>  
</div>
```

Remark: I am not sure if the `rgba` function is invoked with the correct parameters. If you want it to be semi-transparent blue, you could use `rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)`. Right now, it is semi-transparent black with just a tiny bit of blue.